# What is the key for an array element if I don't specify

Tags: php, arrays

I'm wondering if all PHP arrays have to have `key`s for their `value`s? I don't think they do, and so my next question is, does the `key` for each `value` automatically become it's position in the array (0-based indexing), or else does the `value` itself become the `key`?

Perhaps the value simply doesn't have a key... curious, because I can't delete an element from an array inside a `foreach` loop if it doesn't have a key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm wondering if all PHP arrays have to have keys for their values?

Yes, they do.

> Does the key for each value automatically become it's position in the array (0-based indexing)

Yes. If you do not explicitly specify a key value, then it's corresponding position will be used (0-based indices).

> I can't delete an element from an array inside a foreach loop if it doesn't have a key.

You don't always need a key to operate with arrays. Also, `foreach` construct allows you to use the keys inside the array: `foreach ($iterable as $key => $value)`.

Comment: Thanks don't have enough reputation to vote up...sorry

Comment: @edit that's what I have in my code... `foreach ($iterable as $key => $value)`

Answer (score 4):

> I'm wondering if all PHP arrays have to have keys for their values?

Yes.  From the [documentation](https://php.net/manual/language.types.array.php):

> **Arrays**
>
> An array in PHP is actually an ordered map. A map is a type that associates values to keys.

Therefore, all elements of an array must have a key.

> does the key for each value automatically become it's position in the array (0-based indexing)

Almost correct.  If a key is not specified for an element, the key will be 1 + the key of the previous element, with the key of the first element being 0.

> I can't delete an element from an array inside a foreach loop if it doesn't have a key.

There is actually [`foreach`](https://php.net/manual/language.types.array.php) syntax that exposes the key in addition to the value.   From the [documentation](https://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php):

> The foreach construct provides an easy way to iterate over arrays. foreach works only on arrays and objects, and will issue an error when you try to use it on a variable with a different data type or an uninitialized variable. There are two syntaxes:
>
> ```
> foreach (array_expression as $value)
>     statement
> foreach (array_expression as $key => $value)
>     statement
> ```

An example using the latter `foreach` syntax for deleting array elements is as follows:

```
// Remove elements from the array that are less than 10
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if ($value < 10) {
        unset($array[$key]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the extra info. I just wasn't sure if the `$key => $value` script would work since I had never specified `key`s.

Comment: Interesting that if a key is not specified, it isn't assigned a key _according to it's position_ but instead it _adds 1_ to the last key.

Answer (score 1):

Yes the key of each value is 0-based index. you can create an array and var_dump() it to see the keys.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php